# How to perform transaction management in Mule for a single flow having multiple sub flows

Tags: spring, hibernate, mule

I have the following scenario where fdcasterflows1Flow1 and fdcasterflows1Flow2 will have database operations in spring hibernate and should be commit or rollback based on few parameters, I have to perform in DBCommitRollBack class, and for that fdcasterflows1Flow1  and fdcasterflows1Flow2 should get the same database connection, How can this be achieved in mule

```
<flow name="DetailsFlow2" doc:name="DetailsFlow2">
<flow-ref name="fdcasterflows1Flow1" doc:name="Flow Reference1"/>   
<flow-ref name="fdcasterflows2Flow2" doc:name="Flow Reference2"/>              
<component class="com.DBCommitRollBack" doc:name="Java"/>
 </flow>
 <sub-flow name="fdcasterflows1Flow1" doc:name="fdcasterflows1Flow1">
 <component class="com.GetDetails" doc:name="Java"/>
 </sub-flow>
 <sub-flow name="fdcasterflows1Flow2" doc:name="fdcasterflows1Flow1">
 <component class="com.FetchDetails" doc:name="Java"/>
 </sub-flow>
```

By the way I am using HibernateDAOSupport provided by Spring DAO layer

Comment: The fact you are asking this question means already that you are using mule for the wrong task. If you are using DAO this means you have a db structure behind why don't just using spring to to a REST business API ?

Comment: No, we have to use Mule framework because we have various connectors such as HTTP, File etc, is there a way to perform transaction management?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Enterprise Edition, I would recommend using the "Transactional Scope".

From Mulesoft's documentation:

> Apply a transaction as a wrapper (known as a scope in Studio) when you want to apply a transaction to elements within a flow that do not begin with a inbound connector configured as a transaction.

You could return your few parameters back to Mule, and then choose to either proceed or throw an exception (thereby stopping the transaction).

Comment: Is there a relevant section of the documentation that you can quote in this answer? Stack overflow prefers answers to be "self-contained".

Comment: Done - I have edited my answer above. Thank you for the pointer.

Comment: Great, thanks. Btw, you can keep the link to the full docs - the answer is allowed to have external links, as long as it stands on its own without them.

Comment: For example I need to control my transaction as below, using PlatformTransactionManager with a beginTransaction somewhere at the top level of the flow and commit/rollback at the end of the flow? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Just to ask, why do you need to use PlatformTransactionManager? If you are using Mule, you should use their built in tool set when possible. The transaction scope will allow you to wrap whatever you want within a transaction.

As for providing an example using Spring, I am not too familiar with Spring (I come from the C# world), and my workplace will not allow me to provide example code, so I unfortunately can not do so.

Comment: Thank you, I work for a banking application where in we have different services, after visiting all the services, i ought to roll back or commit at the end. I was wondering for a mechanism of that sort, i.e.., flow inside flows, I need to open the trasnaction somewhere in the top of the parent flow and commit at the end, depending on the business logic

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the database connector documentation, especially around transactions.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/database-connector

Comment: this may be helpful, but is not an answer.  see [answer].